# Use Google Analytics to track visitor/download stats for a Google Code Project?

Tags: source-code, google, personal-projects, project-hosting, usage-statistics

Can you use Google Analytics to track visitors/downloaders for a Google Code project?

I've searched google for an answer but I get results about Google Analytics as a Google Code project itself and not for applying it to a Google Code project for visitor/download data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Analytics to track visits and views of Code projects but not downloads as far as I know.

If you look under your project's Administer tab, you'll see towards the bottom that there is a box into which you an enter an Analytics tracking code. That's all there is to it.

Comment: +1 part of the answer - thanks @Adam Crossland. sourceforge.net provide country-level granularity of downloads of the .zip version of a project. Would be nice if google code did the same.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. If I can work out how to track downloads as well I will add that here. I know in theory downloads can be tracked because, for example, I ran a Drupal site with Google Analytics module, I could see which files people were downloading. I think that in that example, .htaccess config file had some intercept hooks that enabled the tracking.

Comment: downloads should have their own tracking on the downloads page? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-code-hosting/lEjGUu2vAR8

Answer (score 0):

Trick to using GA to track downloads is to use javascript to fire off an event (or a pageview) when someone clicks the download link.

No idea how much javascript one can push into a google code page.